# update / select mysql tables in multiple sessions

Tags: python, mysql, django, synchronization

I need to run multiple sessions to select rows in MySQL. In each session, I first select a number of rows with `flag=0`. After that, I set `flag=1` for these rows. 
Simultaneously, I run another session (or more sessions), which does the same thing. However, I am afraid that the selection in one session may conflict with other sessions. 
Is there anything I can do to avoid this conflict?

I am programming using Python and using the Django framework. Does Python or Django have a command like "synchronization" to make sure that these two sessions do not conflict?

Comment: You could lock the rows you selected by using [SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of multisession coordination is not a function of the client language; it's a function of the DBMS.  You select the rows `FOR UPDATE`, then you update them and COMMIT your transaction.

To get this to work, your table needs to use the InnoDB (or XtraDB) engine. MyISAM can't do it.

Your operation will work like this:

```
 START TRANSACTION /* this may have its own function call */

 SELECT id, whatever 
   FROM table
  WHERE flag = 0
  LIMIT 10
    FOR UPDATE;

 /* do what you need to do with each row selected */

 UPDATE table SET flag  = 1 WHERE ID = ?id

 COMMIT;
```

If I were doing this I'd consider using LIMIT 1 and handling one row at a time.  But it should work with multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a clarification. Before "update table set flag=1", the flag is still 0. If I understand correctly, the "for update" will reserve these rows, so another "select" statement won't select these rows. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: That's right. A select statement wanting those rows will block until your transaction either commits or rolls back.